# Store account to Passwords and Accounts (iOS Setting)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to save username and password from app to Passwords & Accounts. From iOS -> Setting -> Passwords & Account, Swift code please or any Apple documentation. Please see the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Passwords and Accounts` holds application's username or password information. It holds website username and passwords

You secure your application's username and password you may want to save it in Apple's `Keychain`. Please referhttps://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services for more details.